# How can I get all of the past months of the current year from DUAL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get only the months that have passed so say in February it would only return January and in December it would return January-November.

This returns all months of the current year.

```
 Select TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE,'year') , LEVEL-1  ), 'YYYY-MM' ) Month
     FROM   dual
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
```

Comment: You probably need number of days/weeks bcs it is more then 1 month past from the beginning of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just need to adjust the number of rows that are returned which is controlled by the `12` in the `CONNECT BY` clause.  Something like this should work

```
 Select TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(SYSDATE,'year') , LEVEL-1  ), 'YYYY-MM' ) Month
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= floor( months_between( sysdate, trunc(sysdate,'YYYY')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly simpler version:

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'), level-1)
from dual
connect by level < to_char(sysdate,'MM');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if one wanted to use intervals and the ANSI `EXTRACT()` function (which avoids the implicit conversion of using `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM')` -- not that it affects the speed at which this query runs in any way whatsoever):

```
 SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') + NUMTOYMINTERVAL(LEVEL - 1, 'MONTH')
   FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE);
```